# Check if a file is locked while another program uses it?

Tags: c

I have this code in **writer.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("f.bin", "wb");
    int fd = fileno(fp);
    flock(fd, LOCK_EX);
    int i = system("./read");
    sleep(2);
    int a = 2;
    fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    sleep(2);
    flock(fd, LOCK_UN);
    fclose(fp);
};
```

How should the **reader.c** file be written to wait for the file to be unlocked?

Comment: `flock(fd, LOCK_EX)` will already wait for any other process's exclusive `flock`-based lock on the same file to be released before it returns.

Comment: Do note, however, that `flock` doesn't work on some filesystem types.  In particular, it does not work on NFS filesystems.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok thanks, so if I make an other programme that will  himself lock the file, he will wait for the "writer" to unlock it

Comment: Yes, or if you run two copies of *the same* program concurrently, then one of them will wait for the other.

Comment: Note that if the `reader.c` program does wait for the file to be unlocked, your programs will be deadlocked because the `writer.c` code wiats for `reader.c` to finish before unlocking the file.

Comment: As noted, waiting is the default behavior.  If you *don't* want to wait, but want `flock` to fail immediately if the file is already locked, use `flock(fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)` (where `NB` stands for "non-blocking").

Comment: Incidentally, the semicolon after the `}` at the end of `main()` is unwanted.  Formally, it is an empty declaration on the same line as the `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @John Bollinger, the easiest way is to use the same flock structure in both program.

```
void some_general_fread(char * file) {
    FILE * fp = fopen(file, "rb");
    int fd = fileno(fp);
    flock(fd, LOCK_EX);

    ///
    // some freads
    
    // Exit
    flock(fd, LOCK_UN);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Same for writing.

And both programs, started with delays, and trying to read during the file modification, will wait until it's done modifying it.